# drawImage Java api

Tags: java, user-interface, drawimage

drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, Color bgcolor, ImageObserver observer)

I would like to specify a null colour for bg colour in the above method. It defaults to black. I thought I could specify null as argument for bgcolor but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

I'm using

drawImage(img, 0, 0, null, this);

It works, but just draws black when I want no colour.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to specify `null` as a colour; what is your goal? Do you want the background to be transparent instead of black?

When this is what you want, try using a colour that has alpha set to 0 (fully transparent):

```
Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, transparent, this);
```

Comment: isnt that storing black with zero alpha? What if i want no colour at all?

Comment: The colour you specify is used for blending with the already existing background. When the colour has an alpha of 0, the already existing background will be preserved. Did you try it out?